# Params not passed to child screen in TabNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

So I have this StackNavigator consisting of a few screens and a TabNavigator with several screens. I am trying to navigate from one screen (SignIn) to another Screen (HomeScreen) which is inside a TabNavigator and pass a param.

Basically the stack looked like this:

```
StackNavigator(router.js):
    - StackNavigator:
        - SignIn
        - SignOut
    - TabNavigator:
        - Home
        - Search
        - Profile
    - AnotherScreen
```

I want to navigate from SignIn to Home and pass a param. Also I want to pass another different param from AnotherScreen to Home so that the screen Home will re render.

router.js

```
export const SignedOut = createStackNavigator({
    SignInPage: {
        screen: SignIn
    }
});

export const SignedIn = createBottomNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
                <FontAwesome name='home' size={ 30 } color={ tintColor } />
        }
    }
}, {
    tabBarOptions: {
        ...
    }
});

export const createRootNavigator = (signedIn = false) => {
    return createStackNavigator({
        SignedIn: {
            screen: SignedIn
        }
    });
}
```

SignIn.js

```
...
    <Button onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('SignedIn', {param: '1'})} />
...
```

HomeScreen.js

```
...
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;
    const param = navigation.state.params.param;
...
```

Now when I press the button in SignIn.js, it redirects to the page SignedIn, which have the initialroute Home, but the param that I passed in the navigation does not get passed to my HomeScreen, it always return no value.

How do I passed the params from my SignIn page to the HomeScreen ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to receive it in ComponentDidMount().

That way it will work!